# Unnamed title appears blank

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a form that I can save the title as blank in this case the function transform the blank as unnamed + primary key. But in my case the saving as blank remains blank . I don't know what is the problem.

The template :

```
 <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Backtesting{% if form.instance.pk %}: {{form.instance.title}} {% endif %}</div>

 <div id="tab1" class="tab"  >

        <form action="{% url "backtest" %}" method='POST' role='form' id='form'>
             {% csrf_token %}
             <input type="hidden" name="tabs"  value="first" id="toggle-tab1"  checked="checked" />

            {% include 'tags/parameters_form.html' %}
            <br />

            {% include 'tags/parameters_backtest_form.html' %}
                            <br />


            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <input type='submit' id='run' value='Run' class='btn btn-default'>

                {% if user.profile.is_active %}
                    Name: {{ form.title }} <input type='submit' name='save' value='Save' class='btn btn-default'>
                {% else %}
                    <p>
                    Expired account! you need to reactivate in order to save parameters.
                    </p>
                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
             Please <a href="{% url 'auth_login' %}">login</a> in order to Run backtesting!
                 </br>
                 Our system needs your email in order to notify you once one or more of your simulations are done. This is a safer way for you to keep track of your previous simulations (/jobs).   

             {% endif %}
```

The models.py :

```
title       = models.CharField('title', max_length=100, default='', blank=True, help_text='Use an indicative name, related to the chosen parameters')

def __unicode__(self):
    if self.title:
        return u'%s' % (self.title)
    else:
        return u'Unnamed%s' % (self.pk)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pk is integer.

You need to format it as integer.

```
return u'Unnamed%d' % (self.pk)
```